# Properties of digital signature of Windows files in Java

Tags: java, windows, timestamp, jna, sign

Is it possible in `Java` with the help of any `API` (desirable API, not by parsing the file) to know the properties of the digital signature Windows files (`exe, dll`, etc.)? Namely: `Signer, Issuer, Digest algorithm, Timestamp, Timestamp signer`. As well as the file description: `Product name, Product Version`. If possible, tell me how, please.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published [example C code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809) for accessing this information.

With JNA you can create appropriate Java-side classes to implement the necessary functions in the [Cryptography API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx).  JNA includes an [initial implementation of the Crypt32 library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32.java) that you can extend and add more functions/methods/constants as needed.